# Y labels precision not working

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to know why the y-axis is not showing the complete number, i.e. precision = 4 when I have all the numbers required to show it so:

```
100 0.895150425339557
200 0.900482595232357
300 0.903679079675768
400 0.905775901961456
500 0.906989289317474
600 0.907739560134421
700 0.908159905497467
800 0.908394225024818
900 0.908519432232782
1000 0.90861411822613
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,width=0.98\textwidth}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,width=0.98\textwidth}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[english]{babel}         % multilenguaje

% grid style

\pgfdeclareplotmark{mystar}{
    \node[star,star point ratio=2.25,minimum size=6pt,
    inner sep=0pt,draw=black,solid,fill=red] {};
}

\decimalpoint


\begin{document}



    % This file was created by matplotlib2tikz v0.7.4.
    \begin{tikzpicture}



    \begin{axis}[
    axis line style={black},
    legend cell align={left},
    legend style={at={(0.7,0.8)}, anchor=west, draw=black},
    tick align=outside,
    x grid style={dashed,black!60},
    xlabel={$K$},
    xmajorticks=true,
    xmin=55, xmax=1045,
    xtick style={color=black},
    y grid style={dashed,black!60},
    ylabel={RMSE},
    ymajorticks=true,
    ymin=0.875453344823198, ymax=0.910193202673888,
    ytick style={black},
    xtick align=inside,
    ytick align=inside,
    grid = none,
    y tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
        fixed,
        fixed zerofill,
        precision=4
    },
    ]
    \addplot [mark =square*,mark options = {fill=blue},line width=1pt,blue, mark size=2.5pt]
    table {%
        100 0.895150425339557
        200 0.900482595232357
        300 0.903679079675768
        400 0.905775901961456
        500 0.906989289317474
        600 0.907739560134421
        700 0.908159905497467
        800 0.908394225024818
        900 0.908519432232782
        1000 0.90861411822613
    };
    \addlegendentry{Bla1}
    \addplot [mark =triangle*,mark options = {fill=red},line width=1pt,red, mark size=2.5pt]
    table {%
        100 0.885569549243323
        200 0.887070668935957
        300 0.888060950115143
        400 0.888591579965093
        500 0.888834814899663
        600 0.888949909904719
        700 0.889000205838998
        800 0.889021628991577
        900 0.889029473681479
        1000 0.889031852416184
    };
    \addlegendentry{Bla2}
    \addplot [mark=*,mark options = {fill=black},line width=1pt,black, mark size=2.5pt]
    table {%
        100 0.877032429270956
        200 0.877298698387484
        300 0.877426754279817
        400 0.877456082749727
        500 0.877463664128281
        600 0.877464908640126
        700 0.877464997368712
        800 0.87746508858427
        900 0.877465105556874
        1000 0.877465107569633
    };
    \addlegendentry{Bla3}
    \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: With `precision=4` you get 4 decimal places, with `precision=2` you would get 2 decimal places.  This is exactly what you see in the output. Could you please clarify what you would like to obtain instead?

Comment: Instead of getting 0.8700, I want the last two numbers to appear as they are in the table, as an example, If I have 0.8774 I don’t want 0.8700, I want the actual number 0.8774

Comment: It has to do with the scale, I have a table filled with 0.8774 and it does not appear whatsoever. I don’t know how to fix it, maybe `y = data ‘ ?

Comment: Is `ymin=0.875, ymax=0.91,
    ytick distance=0.0025,` closer to what you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes, fantastic. One last question. How do I get rid of the comma in the 1,000?

Comment: `\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={}}` removes the thousand separator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of `\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={}}` I have removed the comma in `1,000` to get `1000` instead.

I have also replaced `ymin=0.875453344823198, ymax=0.910193202673888,` with `ymin=0.875, ymax=0.91` in order to align the corresponding ticks with the x axis.

With `precision=4` you requested 4 decimal places. Since the interval between adjacent ticks is `0.005`(3 decmal places), the fourth decimal place is just filed with `0`s as requested with the use of `fixed zerofill`. In order to cirumvent this, we can change the interval with `ytick distance=0.0025`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,width=0.98\textwidth}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={}}  %<----- Added to remove thousand separator

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}



    \begin{axis}[
    axis line style={black},
    legend cell align={left},
    legend style={at={(0.7,0.8)}, anchor=west, draw=black},
    tick align=outside,
    x grid style={dashed,black!60},
    xlabel={$K$},
    xmajorticks=true,
    xmin=55, xmax=1045,
    xtick style={color=black},
    y grid style={dashed,black!60},
    ylabel={RMSE},
    ymajorticks=true,
    ymin=0.875, ymax=0.91,  %<----- Changed
    ytick distance=0.0025,  %<----- Added to change interval between ticks 
    ytick style={black},
    xtick align=inside,
    ytick align=inside,
    grid = none,
    y tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
        fixed,
        fixed zerofill,
        precision=4
    },
    ]
    \addplot [mark =square*,mark options = {fill=blue},line width=1pt,blue, mark size=2.5pt]
    table {%
        100 0.895150425339557
        200 0.900482595232357
        300 0.903679079675768
        400 0.905775901961456
        500 0.906989289317474
        600 0.907739560134421
        700 0.908159905497467
        800 0.908394225024818
        900 0.908519432232782
        1000 0.90861411822613
    };
    \addlegendentry{Bla1}
    \addplot [mark =triangle*,mark options = {fill=red},line width=1pt,red, mark size=2.5pt]
    table {%
        100 0.885569549243323
        200 0.887070668935957
        300 0.888060950115143
        400 0.888591579965093
        500 0.888834814899663
        600 0.888949909904719
        700 0.889000205838998
        800 0.889021628991577
        900 0.889029473681479
        1000 0.889031852416184
    };
    \addlegendentry{Bla2}
    \addplot [mark=*,mark options = {fill=black},line width=1pt,black, mark size=2.5pt]
    table {%
        100 0.877032429270956
        200 0.877298698387484
        300 0.877426754279817
        400 0.877456082749727
        500 0.877463664128281
        600 0.877464908640126
        700 0.877464997368712
        800 0.87746508858427
        900 0.877465105556874
        1000 0.877465107569633
    };
    \addlegendentry{Bla3}
    \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```